# Conditional Rendering inside the Component

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, modal-dialog, conditional-statements, semantic-ui

I have a Semantic UI Modal in separate component and I am calling in another component. This is working fine.

If I add a if condition inside the Modal it's throwing an error.

Below is my code.

Modal.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Icon, Modal as SemanticModal} from 'semantic-ui-react'

const Modal = ({trigger, header, size, dimmer, content, actions}) => (
    <SemanticModal
        trigger={trigger}
        size={size}
        dimmer={dimmer}
        header={header}
        content={content}
        actions={actions}
      />
    )

export default Modal;
```

App.js

```
<Modal
    trigger={<a>Link</a>}
    size={'small'}
    dimmer={'blurring'}
    header={result===""?"<Header icon='spinner loading'/>":"<Header content='Result' />"}
    content={result===""?"<p>Loading...</p>":"<p>showing the result</p>"}
/>
```

The above one is working fine.

But the below one is not working

App.js

```
<Modal
    trigger={<a>Link</a>}
    size={'small'}
    dimmer={'blurring'}

    {
       publishStatus=="" ? (
            header="<Header icon='spinner loading'/>"
            content="Loading..."
       ) : (
            header="<Header content='Result' />"
            content="showing the result"
       )
    }


    header={result===""?"<Header icon='spinner loading'/>":"<Header content='Result' />"}
    content={result===""?"<p>Loading...</p>":"<p>showing the result</p>"}
/>
```

What is wrong in the above method?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?
Not the cleanest approach though

```
        <Modal
          trigger={<a>Link</a>}
          size="small"
          dimmer="blurring"
          {
           ...publishStatus === '' ? {
                header: <Header icon='spinner loading'/>,
                content: 'Loading...',
           } : {
                header: <Header content='Result' />,
                content: 'showing the result',
               }
          }
        />
```

Comment: ya.. That works.. but i am getting an error at `header` tag. it's not recognized  like `size` or `dimmer`. How to make the header and content to Modal attributes?

Comment: I updated the comment, I think `Header` should not be wrapped in commas

Comment: oh... Sorry for the confusion.. I mean the `header:` and `content:` attribute itself not recognized.

Comment: @Dhanapal sorry I dont understand.
Check this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/wkyjk2426l?module=/example.js